# Exception thrown at 0x003165F0 in tStack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x9BFF07EF.?

Tags: c++, list, stack

Exception thrown at 0x003165F0 in tStack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x9BFF07EF.?

I can't seem to nail down the issue on this program. I keep getting read/write errors like this one in different places. Here is the .cpp and .h

.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;

tStack::tStack()
{
}

tStack::~tStack()
{
}

tStack::tStack(const tStack &)
{
}

void tStack::Pop()
{
    snode *tmp_ptr = NULL;

    if (front)
    {

        tmp_ptr->next = front;
        front = tmp_ptr;
        free(tmp_ptr);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\nStack is Empty";
}

void tStack::Push(std::string op)
{
    snode *tmp_ptr = front;

    tmp_ptr->data = op;

    if (front)
    {
    tmp_ptr->next = front;
    front = tmp_ptr;
    }
    else
    {
    front = tmp_ptr;
    front->next = NULL;
    }
}

void tStack::Print()
{
    snode *cur_ptr = front;

    if (cur_ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "\nElements in Stack:\n";
        while (cur_ptr)
        {
            std::cout << cur_ptr->data;
            cur_ptr = cur_ptr->next;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\nStack is Empty";
}

void tStack::cStack()
{
    free(front);
}

void tStack::convert(std::string postfix, tStack a)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool lastOper;
    std::string pusher, val1, val2;

    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(postfix[i]))
        {
            pusher = postfix[i];
            a.Push(pusher);
            count++;

        }
        else
        {

            if (count < 2)
            {
                std::cout << "There are not enough values to perform an operation.";
            }

            else
            {
                pusher = postfix[i];
                val1 = front->data;
                a.Pop();
                val2 = front->data;
                a.Pop();
                a.Push(")");
                a.Push(val1);
                a.Push(pusher);
                a.Push(val2);
                a.Push("(");
            }
            lastOper = true;
        }
    }
}
```

.h:

```
 #pragma once
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;
class snode
{
public:
    std::string data;
    snode *next;
};
class tStack
{
public:
    tStack();
    ~tStack();
    tStack(const tStack &);
    void Pop();
    void Push(std::string);
    void Print();
    void cStack();
    void convert(std::string, tStack);
private:

    snode *front;


};
```

I found some posts suggesting not using using namespace std but that doesn't seem to help. Do I just have a total misunderstanding of how linked lists work?

Comment: Your pointer math is off somewhere. You'll need to debug your program to find out where.

Comment: Thanks, could you clear something up for me? When I say front->next = temp_ptr; am I right in thinking that means front's next pointer value now points at what temp_ptr points at?

Comment: It looks like someone else has already found the problem. If you're getting an access violation error though, that usually means your calculating an address wrong, or your managing your memory poorly. And sorry, it's been a long time since I've dealt with pointers, I don't want to lead you astray.

Answer (score 0):

First glance at your code and I have spotted a bug.

```
front = tmp_ptr;
free(tmp_ptr);
```

This code makes no sense. You actually free memory used as the top of your stack. Fixing these kind of bugs should be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you referring only to the free method or front = tmp_ptr; as well?

Comment: @Perkis only free, you should remember old front and free it

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I would assume that you are trying to implement your home-made linked list in a "stack" fashion (first on, last off and vice-versa); let me know if I am wrong.

I can see a few problems with your code:

**Problem 1**: In your "Pop" method You are trying to use the "front" member without insuring that it is NULL when the method runs for the first time; Add a definition for it within "tStack"'s default constructor that assigns it to NULL.

**Problem 2**: I believe that you want your "Pop" method to remove elements form the list, not add them.  Am I correct?  If so, then your "Pop" method is implemented incorrectly.  Here is a properly written version of your "Pop" method:

```
void tStack::Pop()
{
    if (front)
    {
        snode *tmp_ptr = front;

        front = front->next;


        free(tmp_ptr);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\nStack is Empty";
}
```

**Note:** I implemented this method in a manner that treats your list as "stack".

This code brings up another important topic, you should define a default constructor for your "snode" class, so that it automatically assigns its "next" member to NULL.

**Problem 3:** Your "Push" method is not implemented correctly.
"tmp_ptr" should be assigned to **new** memory, not the first element of the list.

The line:

```
snode *tmp_ptr = front;
```

should be:

```
snode *tmp_ptr = new snode;
```

**Note:** You can shorten your "Push" method by doing this:

```
void tStack::Push(std::string op)
{
    snode *tmp_ptr = new snode;

    tmp_ptr->data = op;

    tmp_ptr->next = front;

    front = tmp_ptr;
}
```

**Note:** This code assumes that the "snode"s' "next" members are always going to be equal to NULL if there is no following element.  This is one reason that it would be good for you to implement a custom default constructor for your "snode" class.

**Problem 4:** The "cStack" method should loop through each element of your list and free each one individually. The current implementation that you have now, only frees the first element.

**Advice:** Any class that contain pointers to dynamically allocated memory that **it owns**, could do to have a custom destructor that clears the dynamic memory that it has allocated. This is applicable even when a method is used to clear the dynamic memory from an outside source, because it is always good to have a backup plan.

However, this advice would not apply to your "snode" class (at least not to its "next" member), because "deleting" one of your list's elements would cause it to set of a chain reaction that would delete all of the following elements.

Well, that is all the problems that I can see. Let me know if my reply helped. :)

**EDIT:**  Your "tStack" class has a blank default constructor:

```
tStack::tStack()
{
}
```

Change it to this:

```
tStack::tStack()
: front(NULL)
{
}
```

Your default destructor is this:

```
tStack::~tStack()
{
}
```

Change it to this:

```
tStack::~tStack()
{
    // Clear the dynamic memory if needed.
    if (front)
        cStack();
}
```

Lastly, add a default constructor to your "snode" class:

```
snode::snode()
: next(NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: WOAH. Thank you! You answered my questions and then some!

Comment: As far as constructors and destructors go I am still learning. Do you know of any resources that could help me write a proper constructor and destructor for linked lists? I've got a bunch of leaks right now it seems. Also, do you know how I could get a b + to be treated the same as ab+?

Comment: By "resources" do you mean resources for linked lists specifically or just for constructors/destructors in general?  Tell me, how much do you know about constructors/destructors?  Did you place that default constructor in your code by yourself, or did you copy and paste it from someone else?  I only ask, because I can give you a constructor and destructor that would work in just a few lines of code, but I want to make sure that you understand what I am telling you. Can you elaborate a little bit on your second question? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  :\

Comment: Ps. I don't know if you used my version of your "Push" method or not, but if you did, I changed it a little bit. I noticed that I made a small mistake.

Comment: I got the constructors by creating the templates in the header and having c++ make definitions in the .cpp file. I could use either I guess.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  I've never heard of that before.  You don't have to use a constructor to automatically assign pointers to NULL, but you must guarantee that, if the pointers are empty, then they are assigned to NULL at some point **before** they are used otherwise there is no way to tell if they point to legitimate memory or not.  I'll edit my answer to give you some constructors and destructors that will help you.    I'm still not sure what you meant when you asked if there is a way to treat "b+" as "ab+".  Are you talking about changing an addition operator into a multiplication/addition hybrid?

Comment: Thanks! No I mean treat a b + the same as ab+ as in disregard spaces.

Comment: Give me a short explanation of what you are trying to achieve, then I can probably give you an answer for your question.

Comment: So here's what I tried but it didn't work. I created a quick for loop that scans through the string input by the user. I would then build a string using each char of the input string but any time the char at the iterator was ' ' I would just skip that. I figure I could do all that in main and not even change my push or pop functions, just build the string and send the rebuilt string to the convert function.

Comment: I took a look at your "tStack::convert" method, and I'm not exactly what it is supposed to do.  It would appear that you are trying to implement a home-made string. Am I correct?  Can you give me a short explanation of what your program's purpose is?  The technique by which you disregard blank spaces within a string depends entirely on your situation.  If you can give me an explanation of what your goal is, I will most likely be able to give you some advice.  Feel free to use more than one comment if you can't fit it all that you want to say on one.